# Two distinct usages of "could" here?

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this dialogue (only the third utterance is made up by me; the rest is from [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/the-nuance-of-could-have-done)):

> A: "You **could<sub>1</sub>** send him an email."
>
> B: "Yeah, I **could<sub>2</sub>** send him an email, but I won't; he
>   only checks his email about once a week. I'll phone him."
>
> A: "He **could<sub>3</sub>** be in a meeting right now. You want to
>   check the schedule before you do."

In my opinion, **could<sub>1</sub>** and **could<sub>3</sub>** share the same usage of expressing factual possibility here, the first utterance representing a suggestion and the third an uncertain assumption. Besides, **could<sub>3</sub>** could be substituted for **may** with the meaning more or less unchanged.

As for **could<sub>2</sub>** I would think it's another story. **I won't** in the utterance cancels the implicature that "I" am likely to send him an email. Thus, I think **could<sub>2</sub>** is different from the other two **could<sub>1&3</sub>**. The other reason for my thinking is that **could<sub>2</sub>** couldn't be substituted for **may** in the context because **may** itself isn't in a preterite form for hypothetical thinking (but **might** would be an alternative for the second utterance), so I believe **could<sub>2</sub>** is a purely hypothetical version of **can**. ( But I'm not sure whether **could<sub>2</sub>** has the same usage as in [[58] The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, aka CGEL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27207/special-use-of-might-and-could).)

If we try to backshift the last two utterance we can see the difference:

> I **could<sub>2</sub>** send him an email, but I won't. ⇒  I
>   **could<sub>2</sub>** have sent him an email, but I didn't. #1
>
> He **could<sub>3</sub>** be in a meeting **right** now. ⇒ He
>   **could<sub>3</sub>** have been in a meeting **just** now. #2

I think #1 is a remote (conditional) construction while #2 is a modal perfect construction, which demonstrates in the original dialogue **could<sub>2</sub>** is different from the other two **could<sub>1&3</sub>**.

Is my understanding on **could<sub>2</sub>** and **could<sub>3</sub>** correct? And is my proof method valid?

Comment: I think I'm done with modal-verbs for now. I wish I didn't present myself like a hair splitter. My intention is just to exhaust all the variations on the usages of several major modal-verbs.

Answer (score 1):

All of the '**could**' uses here are equal meaning that 'it's a possibility'

If I substituted it for '**may**' or '**might**' we would then start talking about the probability of it happening, since it was affirmed that he wouldn't do the action, the use of '**may**' or '**might**' would be very inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

One way I might look at it is like this, in which case the "could" shares the same notion again, because it is somewhat of a quotation.

> A: "You could send him an email."
>
> B: "Yeah, your suggestion is feasible, but I won't follow it."

In this case, B is just saying that the suggestion on behalf of A is a possibility, but he has decided he will not follow through on it.

---

> As for **could<sub>2</sub>** I would think it's another story. **I won't** in the utterance cancels the implicature that "I" am likely to send him an email.

I really do see what you're getting at here. Honestly, I struggle to explain it a bit, but I think the meaning of "could" remains the same. I think all three are expressing the same notion of *it is possible*.

> A: "**It is possible** for you to send him an email."
>
> B: "Yeah, **it is possible** for me to send him an email, but I won't; he only checks his email about once a week. I'll phone him."
>
> A: "**It is possible** that he is in a meeting right now. You want to check the schedule before you do."

---

Either way, **I don't think it's fair to say this is a different meaning of "could"**. The first two sentences could also both be substituted for "be able to" (that is, "You are able to send him an email," "Yeah, I am able to send him an email, but...").

*Keep in mind*, "could" (or "can") and "may" are not always interchangeable.

> Can I defeat Ganondorf? (*questioning ability*)
>
> Could I defeat Ganondorf? (*questioning possibility*)
>
> May I defeat Ganondorf? (*asking permission*)

As a result, I don't think it's fair to map "may" to "could" in this context. It makes the construction a bit awkward, and I think your conclusion is incorrect as a result.

Comment: What about this one: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27207/special-use-of-might-and-could I think it's similar to _could_ in the second utterance. That's another reason for my proof.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Yes, in that cases "may" (or "might") can be substituted with "could". However, here, that is not the case, because it implies giving permission initially ("You are allowed to send him an email."), then responding arrogantly ("Yeah, of course I'm allowed to send him an email, ..."). Because of that ambiguity, we can't assign "may" here and keep the same meaning.

Comment: You need to go over my question more attentively. "**Could3** could be substituted for may with the meaning more or less unchanged." I **didn't** say **Could1**. What you said isn't new to me.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng But you _did_ assume, for your proof, that **could1** and **could3** share the same meaning. A disproof can make the same assumption. (For what it's worth, I disagree with the assumption, but that's irrelevant.)

Comment: That's beside the point. My question is not about may vs could. Let's stay on point. Or, we could wait and see other comments.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I've tried to stick to what I said in my answer (which primarily covered things other than "may"), but I'm struggling to see how the post you've linked changes what I've said. I thought you were referring to the subtlety between _might_ and _could_, but I guess not?

Comment: No, it's not. Plz see the title.

Comment: +1 for making the crucial point that *could* in 1 & 2 only differ because of "contextual implicatures". Arguably 3 is "different" in that the first two are about *having the capability of doing something*, whereas 3 is about *whether or not something is in fact the case*.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes, I could... but he never answers his emails so I'll phone him instead"

Emailing is a possibility, albeit an unlikely one.

I have the ability to email him. I have a networked computer and thus the wherewithal to email him. I am not forbidden to email him. I *can* email him, and I *may* (am free to, am not violating any rule or etiquette) email him, and were it not for the fact that the $*%&%! luddite never answers his emails, I *might*  have emailed him! But I **opt** not to do so.  I'll phone him instead.

So perhaps @Kinzie B, the OP, is looking for the nuance of *option* here? Choice is a particular kind of future possibility. could-1 and could-2 both have to do with choice.